# if A $\in $ M(R) is symmetric with $A^3 + A^2 + 4I = O$, where I is the identity matrix. Determine the matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra

*This question seems alien to me. I don't know which proposition to use to solve it.
The equation seems like Cayley-Hamiliton Theorem, still doesn't help much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By inspection, you can see that a solution of the polynomial $x^3 + x^2 + 4$ is $x = -2$. We then factor it as $(x+2)(x^2 - x + 2)$.

The remaining solutions of the polynomial are complex. Note then that $m_A | x^3 + x^2 + 4$ where $m_A$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$. However, $A$ is symmetric, so it can only have real eigenvalues (solutions of the minimal polynomial are eigenvalues by Cayley-Hamilton). This shows that $m_A = x+2$.

Then, we must have $A = -2I$.